# Netmask and ip are incompatible in dlink dir-300

Tags: ip, router, wifi, netmask

I have Dlink Dir-300 wireless router. I have to set a static ip settings there.
I specify Ip as 192.168.242.3 Netmask: 255.255.0.0. When I press enter it says that the ip is invalid. Although such configuration works on another(linksys) router normally.

When setting the static ip I have control only over last 2 bytes, first two are fixed, so we have 192.168.X.X according to our local network structure.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The netmask should be 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Doesn't work. The gateway ip is 192.168.0.100. When using such netmask it says now that the gateway ip is incorrect.

Comment: Then your IP is completely wrong.  It should be 192.168.0.x with netmask 255.255.255.0.  You're trying to connect to the 192.168.242.x network, that's why you're having the issue.

Comment: My Ip *must* be 192.168.242.3 (242 is the room number, 3 is the 3-d pc of that room). The gateway *must* be 192.168.0.100. The question is how the netmask should be set to be compatible with these settings. Other routers work with 192.168.X.X, netmask 255.255.0.0 normally.

Comment: Okay, sorry to upset you.  It sounds as though you need to set a route between the 2 networks then.   You might be better off asking on a network forum, rather than a programming one.